Can the "Right to be forgotten" and a LLM "non-negotiable attribution" be reconciled? Do they need to?
I was trying to make sense of the impact of the GDPR "Right to be forgotten" rules in accordance to the growing number of LLM partnership the network is announcing lately.

The data subject shall have the right to obtain from the controller the erasure of personal data concerning him or her without undue delay and the controller shall have the obligation to erase personal data without undue delay

This seems to indicate that should someone ask, the company is required to delete their personal data. We can already see that deleted users content is anonymized, thus removing the references to the original account while keeping the actual content (still licensed under Creative Commons).
Yet I struggle to see how this can work with the added layer of LLM trained on the network data, or if they require to in the first place.
We require LLM to implement "non-negotiable" attribution:

if the "attribution" is just "it came from SO", then it is basically no attribution at all.
if the "attribution" contains the actual user name, have we just created an uncontrolled persistence of PII (just suppose the user used their real name)? If that is the case, I can't see a way to maintain it, nor a way to satisfy the requirement of most countries data protection laws
I suppose we could cheat by attributing the source to the actual network question link (that would hopefully always be up-to-date), can the link change in any way that would broke the reference though? Probably a minor issue.

Alas, I am mostly posting this to collect other users ideas and views, and to prompt others to point out other fallacies I may have missed.

Note: I just found this article, it may be relevant: Right to be Forgotten in the Era of Large Language Models: Implications, Challenges, and Solutions

SE's current writeup is very thin on the details - and I'm not entirely sure if the gen AI companies are buying access to data retrieval on demand, a package of data or something else. If its the former - and its live data, it would be simpler than if SE was selling training data with attribution baked in

Is this a question for SE or about LLM in general?

SE specifically, edit the title if you can improve it. To be clear, this is not a generic question for "GenAI"

What action by SE specifically do you think is a problematic with the GDPR's right to be forgotten? They haven't build an LLM (yet).

I would guess that if you trained an llm with attribution - how you would revoke it? It would be like an old data dump in that SE no longer controls it

@Mast short version: I was reading this users concerns about missing attribution in regards to the announced OpenAi partnership and that made me wonder if there is a symmetrical issue with the inability to keep the attribution "up to date"

@JourneymanGeek true. But the dump is just a snapshot of data at a given moment, so no one will probably require you to update an old version. Can a LLM be considered a snapshot? Or is it a product that is required to be updated in some way? Really, as I said, I am mostly brainstorming here. Feel free to post your views as answers, it will be appreciated.

"If the "attribution" contains the actual user name, have we just created an uncontrolled persistence of PII? [...] If that is the case, I can't see a way to maintain it, nor a way to satisfy the requirement of most countries data protection laws." It depends on how the AI model is trained on SO data, I guess. But regardless, once data has been copied/transmitted somewhere else from Stack Overflow, it's no longer Stack Overflow's responsibility to deal with it as part of a GDPR request. You'd need to issue a GDPR request to the company that builds the AI model to do that.

@TylerH Whilst not EU GDPR, the UK ICO guidance is that because SO was responsible for the initial consent, they are also responsible for getting any third partys they sold the data to (like google) to delete any personal data on request: https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/law-enforcement/guide-to-le-processing/individual-rights/the-right-to-erasure-and-the-right-to-restriction/#ib2

@user1937198 mostly what I had in mind, thanks for the information.

As also mentioned in a comment in the announcement post, it is not unlikely that this will be a form of Retrieval-augmented Generation, in which "In response to a query, a document retriever selects the most relevant documents (= some SE questions)", and then "Following document retrieval, the LLM generates an output that incorporates information from both the query and the retrieved documents". This means user attribution and deletion would work exactly the same as on SE currently.

@user1937198 That sounds entirely unenforceable. The data is freely copyable by anyone, and regardless of whether you sell it or let someone else copy it of their own volition, once that's done, you no longer control it. That's not how reality works.

@TylerH Its enforceable because the law makes a distinction between where a data controller has made data publicly available and someone has used it, in which case the burden is 'reasonable steps taking into account cost of implementation', and in case where they have privately transferred data to an entity they have a direct relationship with, where the standard is 'obligation to erase personal data without undue delay'.

@TylerH Or in other words, if an SO publish the data on the Q&A site, and an LLM manufacturer comes along and scapes it, then SO need to stop serving the data when its deleted, but ultimately, they don't know who scraped it. If SO sells the data to the LLM provider directly, then they need to ensure that that data will be used in a way that is consistent with any deletion requests, including any received after the sale, as part of the conditions of the contract of sale.

@TylerH The issue legally is not that LLMs are using data from the network. Its that SO is directly partnering with them, that creates the burden on SO to have the data deleted.

@user1937198 Then it sounds like I already covered that in my comment. If the AI tool just looks at code freshly every time there's a dump then it'll be fixed during the next dump. If it doesn't, that's not SO's problem, it's the AI tool's problem, because it's not SO's code or content anymore.

@TylerH Its depends entirely on if the dump is provided by SO to the LLM vendor specifically, vs downloaded by the LLM vendor from public sources under the standard terms. If its the first, the next dump is not good enough, SO have to proactively get the vendor to remove personal data when they receive deletion request.

@user1937198 considering the old attempts at adding a price barrier for companies that want to use the dump to train LLM, I would also assume that they were planning for that option
